# Math for Buy X Get Y For Z

Tags: math

I'm working on a POS software that require a Buy X Get Y For Z discount schema, i.e: Buy 5 Get 2 For 5$, it means if you buy 7 items, 5 items are normal price and 2 items (6th, 7th) are 5$.

This is the spreadsheet for this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ym93Xqnw6wupBEp9ei711wQPpt3s6QONjcqBO4Xc5X4/edit#gid=0

I want to a algorithm to get X and Y (discounted item) when input quantity

i.e: input quantity and it will return X and Y for Buy 5 Get 2

```
input 7 return X = 5, Y= 2

input 8 return X = 6, Y= 2
..

input 17 return X= 13,Y= 4
```

I'm trying to find formula for this one but I'm failed. Please help me thanks

Comment: Do you mean that `input = 17` should return `x = 13` and `y = 4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 5
y = 2
i = input

r = i % (x + y)
n = (i - r) / (x + y)
py = max(0, r - x) + (n * y)
px = i - py 

return x = px, y = py
```

To explain, I'm setting r with the modulus/remainder of input / (x + y). This is the number remaining after completed offers are removed. I am then setting n to be the number of complete offers by subtracting the remainder from the input and dividing by (x + y). The variable py is then set using n * y for the number of items at the discounted price for completed offers and adding r - x if that is > 0. Finally px is the number of items at full price which is simply the input value - py.

In your spreadsheet, you have not implemented this correctly. Change as follows:

```
G2    =A2-F2
H2    =G2/($L$1+$L$2)
D2    =MAX(0,F2-$L$1)+H2*$L$2
E2    =A2-D2
```

Comment: What answer does it give? I would expect 15 and 2

Comment: The question has been edited since my answer so this was assuming only one offer per customer. So -1 is not really fair.

Comment: It doesn't look like the question has been edited (the -1 vote was not from me, by the way).

Comment: Ok, I changed it. Hopefully it is ok now

Comment: hi Steve,
Your approach is still incorrect.
Please check it again.

Comment: It should work. I've simplified the solution by removing some variables and added brackets to clarify.

Comment: hi Steve, it doesn't work.
Please checkout my update spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ym93Xqnw6wupBEp9ei711wQPpt3s6QONjcqBO4Xc5X4/edit#gid=1372233522 
Thanks

Comment: hi @Steve, this is really awesome.
It's correct some cases except some nonsense cases like as Buy 5 Get 10.
It would be nice if you investigate those cases.
thanks

Comment: How would you make this work for `buy 5 product1 get 2 product2 free`?

Answer (score 2):

For the offer "Buy `x` for $P and get `y` for $Q" you want to work out how many items can be bought at each price if you are buying `q` items in total.

The simplest approach is to iterate through each item, and figure out if it is bought at the cheaper price or the more expensive price -

```
qx = 0
qy = 0

for i = 0 : (q-1)
    m = mod(i, x + y)
    if m < x
        qx = qx + 1
    else
        qy = qy + 1
    end
end
```

Each item will be counted exactly once, so you are guaranteed that `qx + qy = q`.

Comment: hi @Chris, your formula is incorrect at quantity = n(x+y) -1 (6th, 13th. 20th, 27th...)
Please check out.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean - if you are buying 6, you can still get one at the cheap price and 5 at normal price. I'll fix it.

Comment: hi @Chirs,
Do you have any update? I'm really stuck with this. Please help me.
I'm really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @QuocNguyen - I already updated the answer to include this fix (see my edit on 7 Jan). It should be correct for all inputs.

Comment: Thanks Chris,
But this formula is just correct with something like Buy X Get 2 so it's not generic.
Thanks

Comment: No it's not - it works with any `x` and `y`. Why do you say that it only works with y = 2?

Comment: hi @Chris,
Please check out this spreadsheet that I made for you with case Buy 5 Get 3
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ym93Xqnw6wupBEp9ei711wQPpt3s6QONjcqBO4Xc5X4/edit#gid=368257872
Note that:

    q=5=>x=5, y=0|
    q=6=>x=5, y=1|
    q=7=>x=5, y=2|
    q=8=>x=5, y=3
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it could work like this(for the option of BUY 5 GET 2 discounted, it could be generalized for other options):

```
int x = (input/7)*5;
int y = (input/7)*2;
if((input % 7) == 6){
   x+=5;
   y++;
}
else
   x += (input % 7);
```

Where input is your total number of items x is number of full priced items and y of discounted items.

I'm treating the situation of having only one item discounted separately, but there might be way to deal with it easier.